# PHP Mysql Search Prefix

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing search with prefix with PHP/MySQL but like condition give zero records.

I have reference id -HFCT8765865674 and I want search 42891HFCT8765865674 where 42891 is my prefix. I have try strpos and `str_replace` but not working as I will remove prefix from other ids as well.

Mysql query-

```
SELECT * FROM leads where reference_id like '%42891HFCT8765865674%'
```

[image]

Comment: SELECT * FROM  leads where reference_id like '%HFCT8765865674'

Comment: not working i need to search with prefix

Comment: Is there a prefix in the database?

Comment: nope that why i am getting zero records

Comment: If it is not there, then you can not use it when searching

Comment: that why posted that problem here i have use substr function but   length of  reference id is not same

Comment: What is do you want to remove the prefix  before you create query? Is that your goal?

Comment: Is `prefix` always same length?

Comment: yes prefix is same length but  reference id doesnt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove your prefix using `str_replace` if you know what the prefix is.

```
$id = '42891HFCT8765865674';
$prefix = '42891';

$new_id = str_replace($prefix, '', $id);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM  leads where reference_id like '%$new_id%' OR '%$id%'";
```

If you don't know the prefix but know its lenght, you could use `substr`:

```
$id = '42891HFCT8765865674';
$prefix = substr($id, 0, 5);
$new_id = substr($id, 5);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM  leads where reference_id like '%$new_id%' OR '%$id%'";
```

Comment: That is what I thought too. But he mentioned that he tried with str_replace already. But not sure what is his actual goal here. And question is not quite clear actually.

Comment: my goal is to not remove prefix  before query create  because  sometimes in 
 database reference id contain with prefix or without prefix

Comment: @ayush You can just add an `OR` statement

Comment: user3284463@any example

Comment: @ayush does this answer your question?

Comment: @user3284463 thanks,  i am checking all the possibilities

Answer (score 0):

If a prefix is always present in a string and has always the same length:

```
SELECT * FROM `leads` WHERE reference_id LIKE CONCAT('%', SUBSTRING('42891HFCT8765865674' FROM 6));
```